# How do I capture a Felix?

Tags: pocket-army

Occasionally a Felix will show up on the map and it says "Catch Him Now!" When I confront this creature I injure it down to zero health and then it runs away. I don't feel like I am capturing it. I'm playing on a Windows phone if that matters.

Comment: try a pokeball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fight the felix a requisite amount of times and then you will get him.  You can check your "events" to find out how close you are.